Failed ArgoCD ApplicationSet with invalid repository URLs shows as succesful in theArgoCD UI
I have an ApplicationSet with the following content.  Obviously the repo URL is invalid, and I can see error messages in the kubernetes logs for argocd-applicationset-controller.  Yet when I sync in the UI it result is success (with nothing delivered of course).  Is there something that can be configured for ArgoCD UI to show an actual failure?  This can result in silent errors especially if there is partial delivery.
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: ApplicationSet
metadata:
  name: environments
spec:
  generators:
    - git:
        repoURL: 'https://your-repo-url/argo-apps'
        revision: main
        directories:
          - path: 'environments/*'
  template:
    metadata:
      name: '{{path.basename}}-{{appName}}'
    spec:
      project: default
      source:
        repoURL: 'https://your-repo-url/argo-apps'
        targetRevision: main
        path: 'apps/{{appName}}/overlays/{{path.basename}}'
      destination:
        server: '{{clusterURL}}'
        namespace: '{{path.basename}}-{{appName}}'
      syncPolicy:
        automated:
          prune: true
          selfHeal: true

